# How to get a particular view from user is in selection dialog?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to get particular view and it's data when I am in `FileDialog`. 
Currently I am using the code :

```
IWorkbenchPage workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

If I use the above code, I am gettting NPE, as I am currently in `FileDialog` and clicked 'Save' button.

Comment: What is this `UserSelectionDialog`? Is that a class you wrote yourself? That doesn't look like an Eclipse API.

Comment: @rcjsuen : I mean it's a FileDialog.

Comment: You can't do this easily in FileDialog. You should do this in the code calling FileDialog. If you are trying to select things in the workspace FileDialog is probably not the right dialog to use. Explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active window is the modal dialog, which does not support views.

You may have to get

```
IWorkbench.getWorkbenchWindows()
```

And go thru the list of windows, to be able to find a specific view.

BUT, this sounds like a hack, because if the FileDialog needs something from within a specific view, why not submitting the information in the constructor of your own FileDialog implementation (which extends from FileDialog)? In this case you do not have to search for a specific view, you would have the instance directly.